# How can understand semantic meaning for different value?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, finance, xbrl

I want to get `apple's financial data` , download `https://www.sec.gov/files/dera/data/financial-statement-and-notes-data-sets/2022_01_notes.zip` from `https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-and-notes-data-set.html`.Extract it and put it in the `/tmp/2022_01_notes`.You can get the table `sub,num` and field definiton in the webpage `https://www.sec.gov/files/aqfsn_1.pdf`.

I compute the zip file's MD5 message digest.

```
md5sum  2022_01_notes.zip
b1cdf638200991e1bbe260489093bf67  2022_01_notes.zip
```

You can download it from official webpage or my dropbox:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ntwasipze8vr29/2022_01_notes.zip?dl=0
```

No matter where you download it from ,please check the md5sum value,maybe SEC uploaded wrong file and they will update the zip file in the future.

```
import pandas as pd
df_sub = pd.read_csv('/tmp/2022_01_notes/sub.tsv',sep='\t')
df_sub[df_sub['cik'] == 320193]  #apple's cik is 321093
df_sub
                      adsh     cik       name     sic countryba stprba     cityba  ...               instance nciks aciks pubfloatusd floatdate floataxis floatmems
4329  0000320193-22-000006  320193  APPLE INC  3571.0        US     CA  CUPERTINO  ...  aapl-20220127_htm.xml     1   NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4731  0000320193-22-000007  320193  APPLE INC  3571.0        US     CA  CUPERTINO  ...  aapl-20211225_htm.xml     1   NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

`0000320193-22-000007` is a access number for its 2022Q2 data.

```
df_num = pd.read_csv('/tmp/2022_01_notes/num.tsv',sep='\t')
#get all apple's financial data in xbrl concepts format
df_apple = df_num[df_num['adsh'] == '0000320193-22-000007' ]
#extract only one concept ----RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax
#it is revenue mapping into financial accountant concept from xbrl taxonomy.
df_apple_revenue = df_apple[df_apple['tag'] == 'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax']
df_apple_revenue_2021 = df_apple_revenue[df_apple_revenue['ddate'] == 20201231]
df_apple_revenue_2021
```

It is too long to display the dataframe on my terminal console,i write into a excel

```
df_apple_revenue_2021.to_csv('/tmp/apple_revenue_2021.csv')
```

and show it in the excel,paste the content here.

[image]

For the first two lines ,what does `8285000000` and `15761000000` mean?Please give a rational description for `8285000000` and `15761000000`.

```
0000320193-22-000007    RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax us-gaap/2021    20201231    1   USD 0xf159835fd3644f228d15724ad9d1837c  0   8285000000      0   1       0.013698995 5   -6
0000320193-22-000007    RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax us-gaap/2021    20201231    1   USD 0x58c22680ab8dbbfb662ff4e14055c1bd  1   15761000000     0   1       0.013698995 5   -6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain these figures, you have to tie back to the filing from which they were extracted. In this case, the filing with the `accession-number` of `0000320193-22-000007` is [Form 10-Q For the Fiscal Quarter Ended December 25, 2021](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000007/aapl-20211225.htm). If you check in that filing, you'll find, for example, seven of the `value` numbers in your dataframe in the table `Net sales by reportable segment` specifically `Three Months Ended December 26,2020`.

So, for example, `8285000000` refers to the `Japan` segment for that period, while `15761000000` is in the `Net sales by category` table for the `Services` category for the same reporting period. That table contains six more of the `value`s in the dataframe.